Can't find servicenow search box to enter text
I'm using a servicenow testing instance where I'm trying to find the element for the search box, and I've tried it by ID, by XPath, and other things but so far it keeps giving me the NoSuchElementException. HTML snippet: https://pastebin.com/1Yx7yxmi
In there you'll see it has an ID for what I think is the searchbox as (showing the xpath I'm copying to try and find it by that): //*[@id="sncwsgs-typeahead-input"]
I've tried things like: var searchElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("sncwsgs-typeahead-input"));
Any ideas? I'm sure its entirely possible I am just really bad with selenium and HTML, so anybody who has tested this and had it working and might know any tricks, that would be handy right now!
I also tried this full xpath:
/html/body/macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010//div/sn-canvas-appshell-root/sn-canvas-appshell-layout/sn-polaris-layout//div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/sn-polaris-header//nav/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/sn-search-input-wrapper//sn-component-workspace-global-search-typeahead//div/div/div/div/input

MORE INFO:
What works and what doesn't is shown here:
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
var myElement = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010"))); // this works
var shadowRootElement = myElement.GetShadowRoot(); // no error from here
// this below does not work
//var myElement = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.CssSelector("macroponent-f51912f4c700201072b211d4d8c26010 /deep/ dxcsnas-root")));
//var shadowRootElement = myElement.GetShadowRoot();

The element is nested inside multiple shadow-root items - I'm not certain if that is the problem here. I've tried using the selenium c# function "element.GetShadowRoot()" and it doesn't give me any error on the first element I found when searching further and further "up" the xpath. But all subchildren / sub-shadow-roots don't allow me to get them for some reason.
If you want to see the whole site html:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1muvP1FPBh-MGuzKRxGcE8CVZ4lvGWGpp
If it matters I'm trying to use chrome driver - I did see an issue a while back with others having problems accessing things inside shadow dom on chromedriver after a version in 2022 - though I don't know if that has anything to do with this.
Would be nice to do this the right way and learn how rather than manually move the mouse into position and click it with other non-selenium code!

Please [edit] your question to include a representative amount of the HTML you are working with. Enough to answer your question. This will likely include all relevant ancestor nodes.

I also suggest creating a temp account and password if people need to log in. Do not post sensitive information! And passwords are sensitive information, even if only for your dev environment. Better to create a burner account that can be disabled or removed after you get an answer. And all the more reason to include the HTML in your post.

@GregBurghardt I will edit soon, looking into that now

Can you double check the search box in not a Frame then you need to switch the Frame using its locator other wise have already switched frame prior to perform this action, then you need to switch back to Default
Tryout this below example from the browser console and see if if this is identifying the element
If you want to find an element by its id and interact with it using JavaScript directly in the browser console, you can use the document.getElementById method. Here’s the equivalent code in JavaScript:
var searchElement = document.getElementById("sncwsgs-typeahead-input");

After you retrieve the element, you can manipulate it or trigger actions like setting its value, focusing on it, or even simulating a click. For example, if you want to type some text into the input field, you could do:
searchElement.value = "your text here"; // Sets the value
searchElement.focus(); // Focuses on the element

Or, if you want to simulate a click:
searchElement.click();

Just paste these lines into the browser console to execute them.

The page has lots of shadow-root this might be the issue

Yes I think that might have something to do with it - I'm going to look into how to properly handle sites with shadow-root, and see what I can figure out here

I was able to find a C# function to find shadow root (with "myElement.GetShadowRoot();" ) and it doesn't throw an error during tests, so it seems to find the first element I could find by xpath searching (the macroponent one), and its shadowroot - but then getting ahold of the children of that shadowroot (checking for things like ID, xpath), and then subsequent shadowroot elements is not working for me, always no such element. I can't find good tutorials that cover this either :( - any more ideas how to handle the nested shadow root setup like this? - please see full HTML I've added above

Ok you pointed me in the right direction, couldn't find good info because I was searching for all the wrong stuff, but once I figured out what a shadow DOM is and what these shadow-root objects are for, I ended up figuring it out. Posting an answer for others struggling like I was haha

What ended up working:
var shadowParent = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("macroponent-abc123"));
var shadowRoot = shadowParent.GetShadowRoot();

var somethingInsideShadowRoot = shadowRoot.FindElement(By.CssSelector("table"));

I had to wrap my head around shadow DOM and its purposes on websites, then I was able to get it sorted out. Thanks to Rahul for pointing me in the right direction!
